# Jsoup: unable to select all rows within tbody id

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

I have this html file which already crawled and saved from the forum. I want to extract all the thread title from the crawled data and the problem is that it manages to put out some of thread title but not all instead it skip some of the thread title.

I have attached the sample of actual HTML. NOTE: "threadbits_forum_2" the 2 is running number

```
<tbody id="threadbits_forum_2">
<tr>
    <td>Thread1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Thread2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Thread3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Thread4</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
.
</tbody>
```

Java coding:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements threadsList = doc.select("tbody[id^=threadbits_forum]").select("tr");
        System.out.println(threadsList.toString());
```

Outcome:

```
 <tbody id="threadbits_forum_2">
<tr>
    <td>Thread2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Thread4</td>
</tr>
```

Any workaround to get all the thread title?

Thanks for reading my post.

Keith

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a for() statement to scan over all the names.

```
Elements threadsList = doc.select("tr");
for(thread : threadsList){
      String title;
      Elements titles = thread.select("td");
      title = titles.text();
}
```

It helps if there are attributes in each one. So instead of just tr or td, it would be something like select("tr[class=threadClass]"). I assume you are just not posting the attributes in each one.

Try something like that.

EDIT: I'll try and explain how JSoup works, it might give you a better idea of how to code with it. When you create an Elements object, you specify in the select() method, what elements you want it to scan for. So it will scan ALL of the HTML, looking for ANY element that has tr or td in it. It then puts those into the Elements array. You will then have to scan through that array with a for() statement to get the information you want out of those elements. When you only specify the element WITHOUT any attributes, it will retrieve any part of the HTML with a tr or td element. This usually causes errors because on sites normally there are multiple areas containing these elements, so it will return more than you want.

Comment: Hi, Thanks unfortunately the tr tag did not any class only td has class and id.

Comment: Hi, I tried your method and I still get the same error. It only get some of threads title.
    Elements threadsList = doc.select("tbody[id^=threadbits_forum]").select("tr");
    for(Element e: threadsList)
    {
       //To get the title
       System.out.println("Title: " + e.select("a[id^=thread_title]").text());
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your query is asking for the wrong tbody id. In the html the tbody has an id of "threadbits_forum_2" and your code is searching for an id of "threadbits_forum". I would recommend the following change:

```
Element tbody = doc.getElementById("threadbits_forum_2");
Elements trs = tbody.getElementsByTag("tr");
//verify trs.size() is correct
for (Element tr : trs) {
    //do whatever you want
}
```